# Exception from sub geo id XXX TypeError: Cannot read property 'lng' of null

Tags: javascript, meteor, geolocation

Im using Mdg:geolocation and have the below application.

To find user's current location and retrieves posts that are within a distance from user (Got error, page stuck at loading screen). `lng` of null implies that `loc` is undefined.

**Pub**

```
  Meteor.publish('geo', function(loc) {     
    return Posts.find({
      "loc": {            // error line for server.js 13:30
        $near: {
          $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [loc.lng, loc.lat] }, 
           .....
```

**Router**

```
Router.route('/near/:postsLimit?', { 
  name: 'nearPosts',
  waitOn: function(){ 
    return Meteor.subscribe('geo');
  }
});
```

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your route (reproduced below), there is only a `this.params.postsLimit`, no `this.params._id`

```
Router.route('/near/:postsLimit?', { 
  name: 'nearPosts',
  waitOn: function(){ 
    return Meteor.subscribe('geo', this.params._id); //to change reference id
  }
});
```

Therefore the publish function is throwing an error because there is no `loc` to get `loc.lng`

Your route contains `/near/:postsLimit?`. For `this.params._id`, you need something like `/near/:_id` or `/near/:_id/:postsLimit?`, which would give you both. See [docs](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router).

**EDIT:** It looks like you need to have some location data object containing latitude and longitude ready to pass into your subscription like so:

```
Router.route('/near/:postsLimit?', { 
  name: 'nearPosts',
  waitOn: function(){ 
    return Meteor.subscribe('geo', locationObject);
  }
});
```

It is up to you to figure out what `locationObject` to use.

Comment: See edited answer. You can use `/near/:_id/:postsLimit?`, but why pass `_id` into the 'geo' pub-sub?

Comment: Thanks @FullStack. I have removed id reference as it is not relevant as you have pointed. Problem still exists and I have updated the error messages

Comment: When you subscribe to `'geo'`, it expects the first argument to be a `loc`. In your updated code, you are not passing any arguments in `Meteor.subscribe('geo')`

Comment: Hi I removed `_id` as an argument, I guess I misinterpreted your reply. Perhaps you can help write some sample lines to explain? Because your attached code repeats what I have. Not too sure where to tweak stuff. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Thinkerer sure thing. I updated my answer. You need to pass a `locationObject` of some sort to the subscription